# Tried adding database file to assets folder and modifying the sqliteopenhelper class but still application force closes on the phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wanted to load a database along with my apk file.But the application force closes on my phone despite adding the database to the assets folder and modyfying the sqliteopenhelper 
The sqliteopenhelper class

```
public class openingclass extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public openingclass(Context c) {
            super(c,Db_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }
         public void createDataBase() {

                boolean dbExist;
                try {

                     dbExist = checkDataBase();


                } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new Error("database dose not exist");

                }

                if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
                }else{

                    try {

                        copyDataBase();


                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new Error("Error copying database");

                    }
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();


            }

            }

            /**
              * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
              * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
              */
            private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH +"/"+ Db_NAME;

                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.
                throw new Error("database does't exist yet.");

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
            }

            /**
              * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
              * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
              * This is done by transfering bytestream.
              * */
            private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{



                    //copyDataBase();
                    //Open your local db as the input stream
                    InputStream myInput = c1.getAssets().open(Db_NAME);

                    // Path to the just created empty db
                    String outFileName = DB_PATH +"/"+ Db_NAME;
                    File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH);
                     // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
                    if (!databaseFile.exists()){
                        databaseFile.mkdir();
                    }

                    //Open the empty db as the output stream
                    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    //Close the streams
                    myOutput.flush();
                    myOutput.close();
                    myInput.close();



            }



            @Override
            public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

                super.close();

            }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            String S = "create table " +
                    TABLE_NAME +
                    " (" +
                    TABLE_COL_MAIL + " text primary key," +
                    TABLE_COL_NAME + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_PASS + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_PHO + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_ADD + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_GEN + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_DOB + " text" +
                    ");";
            arg0.execSQL(S);

            String S1 = "create table " +
                    SECOND_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (" +
                    TABLE_COL_USER + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_PRODUCT + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_QUANTITY + " integer" +
                    ");";
            arg0.execSQL(S1);




        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Also i added the two variables as

```
private final String DB_PATH="data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/";
    private final String Db_NAME = "dbshopkart.db";
```

Comment: post your logcat then

Comment: It works fine on the emulator not on the actual phone.How do i post the logcat for an execution on the phone?

Comment: debug your app in Real Physical Device

Comment: You DB path is possibly incorrect (missing the leading slash) - and is not something you should be hard coding to begin with, as it will be different on different Android installs.  Also, why do you say "asset folder" in the title when the location you seem to be trying to use is an actual file in the internal storage **not an asset**.

Comment: will adding a leading slash fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on the Emulator, then your code is most probably fine. So there must be something wrong in the internal data of the device. Did you already have the app installed on your phone before you made these changes in the database? If yes, then uninstall the application and run it again. I think it is working on your emulator because the emulator creates a fresh AVD every time, so there is no existing data. Try to uninstall from your device and run it again.